# Having Trouble With Copy Constructor

Tags: java, copy-constructor

I'm having trouble create a good copy constructor.  I want to be able to make a new `PizzaOrderNew` object that will not change when the object that it is a copy of changes.  The problem is, my `PizzaOrderNew` instance variables are all objects of another class, Pizza with instance variables, cheese, size, ham, pepperoni as well as typical accessors and mutators.
 I've tried:

```
public PizzaOrderNew(PizzaOrderNew otherPizzaOrderNew)
{
    pizza01.setSize(otherPizzaOrderNew.pizza01.getSize());
    pizza01.setHam(otherPizzaOrderNew.pizza01.getHam());
    pizza01.setCheese(otherPizzaOrderNew.pizza01.getCheese());
    pizza01.setPepperoni(otherPizzaOrderNew.pizza01.getPepperoni());           
}
```

but this throws an exception. I've tried:

```
public PizzaOrderNew(PizzaOrderNew otherPizzaOrderNew)
{
    pizza01 = otherPizzaOrderNew.pizza01;        
}
```

but this makes it so the copy changes when the original does

Comment: Can you post PizzaOrderNew class and what Exception it gives?

Comment: The second snippet "fails" because what you really assign is a reference to the object, not the value of the object itself. In other words, your copy is not a copy at all.

Comment: Dici is correct, I get a null pointer exception.  I am trying out Dici's solution right now.  I've initialized pizza01 to default values and it still generates a NullPointerException.  I believe Dici and tommyo are both correct, there is just something small that is missing.  Is there anymore information you would all like about the class?  thank you all very much again

Comment: Show us how you tried to fix it initializing `pizza01` and try to print `otherPizzaOrderNew.pizza01`.

Comment: Dici, I initialized pizza01 incorrectly, I fixed that and the program worked just fine.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you get a `NullPointerException` because `pizza01` is not initialized. Initialize it with some default values and then set its attributes as in your first snippet.